# Converting Crystal Report to SSRS. Need to Suppress Items

Tags: reporting-services

We are moving our Crystal Reports over to SQL Reporting Services. Most report are being built with little issues. However, I have a few complicated reports that have suppress Headers or Items in them. Currently I have a Header that needs to Print only if certain criteria is met. I set this up to Hide and it works. The issue is when hidden it still has the Large Header Field in the Report but just blank. If I cannot suppress the header completely the only options is have the user export to Word and fix it there, then export to PDF. This report also has Page Headers (multiple as Crystal allows) and Report Headers again multiple. Is there any functions in SSRS that will allow me to do something similar?

Thanks,
New to SSRS
Rich V

Comment: depending on your report design, you might be able to use a group header rather than a page header and then show/hide that row. This will collapse the space correctly.

Comment: Alan I believe that can work for what I am looking to do. Thank You.